Run a snap package with X11 forwarding of the app using SSH connection and VcXsrv on windows
I'm trying to run a snap application using a ssh connection but I got some problems, here the steps:

Run VcXsrv on Windows
Open terminal and run following commands:

.
export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
ssh -Y user@host
snap run <app_name>

Error

X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
[3243:0411/161835.121241:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(239)] Missing X
server or $DISPLAY
[3243:0411/161835.121312:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The
platform failed to initialize.  Exiting. Segmentation fault (core
dumped)


I resolved the issue exporting the XAUTHORITY variable before running the snap:
export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority && snap run <app_name>

